# Why Jadeite Coffee Cups in Science Fiction Series?

Tags: fringe, props

I have noticed many times in science fiction series like Fringe that characters will use a jadeite coffee cup.  I was wondering what the significance is to this popular recurring prop?  I tried to do a Google search but didn't come up with anything.

Comment: It's likely that it was just a prop that was already in storage, or was inexpensive. I doubt there's an in-universe explanation.

Answer (score 1):

It's because most of the american series and movies are shot in the same place. And it saves a lot of money and problems (eventual suing from the brand) for them to use a brand or a name that has already been used and tested before.

Have a look at the newspaper prop story as an example:
http://www.slate.com/blogs/browbeat/2010/06/07/the_story_behind_the_recycled_newspaper_prop.html